# Update multiple elements inside of a div using AJAX

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, flask

So I am working on a project where I take values from an API using Python Flask and show a bunch of values such as the `Buy Price´ and` Sell Price´ of a specific item.

I started off this project, by just using a table, and it worked completely fine, but for my design, I want to have "cards" instead of a table. So I made the design, and I started to hook in AJAX for this. But it does not work!

I have tried a few different things, but no luck. It either crashes the website or it just stacks every single buy price of ALL items, such as this:
[image]

Here is my HTML code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}
<nav>
  <div class="navigation">
    <ul class="nav-link">
      <li class="nav-item"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>home</li>
      <li class="nav-item"><i class="fas fa-coins"></i>flipper</li>
      <li class="nav-item"><i class="fas fa-gavel"></i>auction house</li>
      <li class="nav-item active"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i>bazaar</li>
      <li class="nav-last">made by: pumbalo</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    {% for item, buyPrice, sellPrice, buyVolume, sellVolume in zip(name, buy, sell, buyvolume, sellvolume) %}
    <div class="card">
      <h2 class="product"><img
        class="card-img"
        src="{{url_for('static', filename='IMG/cobble.png')}}"
        alt=""
      />{{ item }}</h2>
      <div class="card-info">
        <p class="card-text left" style="grid-area: a">Buy Price: <span class="item-info" id="random_decimal">{{ buyPrice }} <img class="card-coin" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='IMG/ICONS/coin.svg')}}" alt="Coin"></span></p>
        <p class="card-text left" style="grid-area: b">Sell Price: <span class="item-info">{{ sellPrice }}  <img class="card-coin" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='IMG/ICONS/coin.svg')}}" alt="Coin"></span></span></p>
        <p class="card-text left" style="grid-area: c">Buy Volume: <span class="item-info">{{ buyVolume }}</span></p>
        <p class="card-text left" style="grid-area: d">Sell Volume: <span class="item-info">{{ sellVolume }}</span></p>
        <p class="card-text card-text-right" style="grid-area: e">Margin:</p>
        <p class="card-text card-text-right" style="grid-area: f">Demand:</p>
        <button class="btn right" style="grid-area: g">View More</button>
      </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
</div>

<script>
  $(function () {
    window.setInterval(function () {
      loadNewDecimal();
    }, 5000);

    function loadNewDecimal() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/price_update",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
          $(random_decimal).replaceWith(data);
        },
      });
    }
  });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

`table_update.html`:

```
{% for buyPrice in buy %}
<div id="random_decimal">{{  }}</div>
{% endfor %}

<!-- I have tried taking the entire "card" code here as well, and also done only {{ buy }}, but it did not work!-->
```

And here is the 2 python functions for this HTML file:

```
@app.route('/price_update', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def price_update():
    data = requests.get(
        'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key='+key).json()
    sell = [product['sell_summary'][0]['pricePerUnit']
            for product in data['products'].values() if product['sell_summary']]
    buy = [product['buy_summary'][0]['pricePerUnit']
           for product in data['products'].values() if product['buy_summary']]
    buyvolume = [product['quick_status']['buyVolume']
                 for product in data['products'].values() if product['quick_status']]
    sellvolume = [product['quick_status']['sellVolume']
                  for product in data['products'].values() if product['quick_status']]
    name = [product['product_id']
            for product in data['products'].values() if product['product_id']]

    return jsonify('', render_template('table_update.html', sell=sell, buy=buy, name=name, buyvolume=buyvolume, sellvolume=sellvolume))


@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    data = requests.get(
        'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key='+key).json()
    sell = [product['sell_summary'][0]['pricePerUnit']
            for product in data['products'].values() if product['sell_summary']]
    buy = [product['buy_summary'][0]['pricePerUnit']
           for product in data['products'].values() if product['buy_summary']]
    buyvolume = [product['quick_status']['buyVolume']
                 for product in data['products'].values() if product['quick_status']]
    sellvolume = [product['quick_status']['sellVolume']
                  for product in data['products'].values() if product['quick_status']]
    name = [product['product_id']
            for product in data['products'].values() if product['product_id']]

    return render_template('index.html', sell=sell, buy=buy, name=name, sellvolume=sellvolume, buyvolume=buyvolume)
```

Comment: Hi what does `data` brings you back ? Also , what is `$(random_decimal)` isn't that should be `$("#random_decimal")` ?

Comment: I return the values as json, as you can see in `return jsonify('', render_template('table_update.html', sell=sell, buy=buy, name=name, buyvolume=buyvolume, sellvolume=sellvolume))`, I then use AJAX to take the values from `/price_update` and replace it on the elements with the ID `random_decimal`

Comment: Hi, so the problem is you are not able to display html correctly ?what is excepted op ?

Comment: I get multiple issues, different from what im testing though. Sometimes it crashes the website, sometimes nothing happens at all and sometimes it adds all values to the text (as seen in the picture)